# Как сверстать горизонтальный таймлайн с закруглением?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильней сверстать такой таймлайн? Есть идеи сделать на абсолютах, но не будет адаптивно.

Comment: Теоретически, можно использовать SVG.

Comment: Кстати, а как это на мобильном должно выглядеть?

Comment: На мобилках элементы друг под другом

Comment: тогда на SVG делайте - откройте любой векторный редактор и нарисуйте

Comment: Адаптив для мобильных делать?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pogavWG - вот на svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот результат.
Адаптивно, для мобильных нормально.
[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_SD/bct4s7zy/)

```css
/* Шрифт - просто для аккуратности */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

:root {
  /* Цвета */
  --bg: #ffffff;
  --fg: #000000;
  --line: #e5e5e5; /* Цвет линий */
  --primary: #90be6d; /* Цвет финиша */

  /* Некоторые вешь, не очень важные */
  background: var(--bg);
  color: var(--fg);
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

/* Закругление линии */
.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 51px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px dashed var(--line);
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom-line {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.line-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

/* Основная часть пунктира */
.line-item::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px dashed var(--line);
}

/* Пунктир у финиша */
.line-item.line-item-finish::before {
  left: unset;
  width: 60px;
  right: -5px; /* Поправка для правильного пунктира */
}

.bottom-line .line-item {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.line-item .text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.circle {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 #00000015;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--bg);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line-item-finish .circle {
  margin: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--primary);
}

.circle img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

/* Адаптив */

/* Вероятное, в зависимости от текста надо будет поправить */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  
  .timeline {
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .timeline::after {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .line {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: unset;
  }
  
  .line-item {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start !important;
  }
  
  .line-item .text {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  
  .line-item::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 2px dashed var(--line);
    border-top: none;
  }
  
  .line-item.line-item-finish::before {
    bottom: unset;
    height: 60px;
    right: -5px; /* To fix dashes */
    left: 51px;
    top: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- TODO: Добавить флажок над финишом -->
<section class="timeline">
  <div class="line top-line">
    <div class="line-item">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/factory.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Начало</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/co2.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Это шаг второй</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/chemical-storage-tank.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">И третий</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line bottom-line">
    <div class="line-item">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/recycling.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">На новой линии</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item">
      <div class="circle">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/eco-fuel.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Конец</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line-item line-item-finish">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Добавил адаптивность.

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили)